# Clang & libc++ on BeagleBoard

Tags: c++, clang, beagleboard, libc++

I am having some serious trouble with Clang on a Beagleboard (with BeagleBoard Debian Jessie).

I have this minimal non-working example :

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

When compiling with `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp`, I get :

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc++.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_RaiseException' 
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc++.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SetIP'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc++.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SetGR'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc++.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetIP'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is happening ? It's working fine on Debian Jessie.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, I'm running into the same issue...

Comment: Hello, IIRC I retried a few months later with upgraded packages and it worked; and I remember seeing a post on the debian mailing-list about buggy packages that had to be rebuilt so...